# Asking a moderator a question directly, a private message

Tags: support, moderators

I was just wondering if there is a way to directly communicate with a certain moderator with a private message. Just to help get a couple clarifications on one or two things.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, no, not directly. (and its for the best! I would not want to wake up every 2 mins with other peoples "issues" :))

You can contact us via the general chat or the regulators room by pinging us with @foo_user, we normally keep an eye on those 2 rooms and if the moderator you pinged is not there I am sure the community or some other imba user will be there to help you.

Other than that use the comments under posts using the same method (@foo_user) or if you think some thing needs to be solved and you need to actually discuss it with the community you should open a question on meta (such as this one migrated by a moderator to the right place).

Comment: Ok, so seeing as to how I am making errors, or mistakes in how I use "Ask Ubuntu" where is the guidelines so I can go over those again? Again I thank you for your straightforwardness and having you explain why you did what you did with my post.
Thank you!

Comment: [General chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) is always a nice place for that, also read the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) -if you did not yet- but more important than all is to not take things serious or personal, we are trying to make this the best we can, if you see bad behaviour report it by flagging it and expect edits on stuff that have nothing to do with posts, this is a community driven site, in the end the community will prevail, not matter how many moderators exist or do stuff around.

Comment: Okay, thank you Bruno.

Comment: If you have general questions on how to us4e the site then just post here on meta, it's why we have it!

Comment: Okay, thank you Jorge.....man I see your name EVERYWHERE , you must be one busy guy!