# Is there a way to contact mods privately?

Tags: support, moderation, moderators

The question says it all. Is it possible to contact the mods privately (thus not in public chat nor in meta)?

Are self-made chatrooms private? Is there a general email like mods@askubuntu.com?

Comment: You could flag a post you know. They are mostly private and are treated with confidence.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Are flags not also visible to trusted users? And what if you want to contact a mod for something that is not related to a post?

Comment: or you can ask to a mod.They will create a separate chat room, through that you can talk to a mod. After the conversation is completed, mods will delete that chat room .

Comment: Think Bruno's answer here is probably the best advice - http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3185/asking-a-moderator-a-question-directly-a-private-message?rq=1

Comment: No, if you flag a post, choose other and give a message, only mods can see that. It is not visible in the 10k flag queue (I have >10k on other sites).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do a custom flag, only moderators and Stack Exchange employees can see that. If you want to have a discussion, you can ping someone on chat and they will assist you.

Failing that, I do publish my email, and so do several others of the moderators, but We will probably just move the conversation to a private chat room as soon as we get it.